# ¿Como puedo hacer para descargar un archivo xls, que dentro de una columna contiene una imagen. Se muestre en el archivo XLS?

Tags: php

Le agregué el siguiente codigo en el archivo que genera el documento excel.

```
$objDrawing = new PHPExcel_Worksheet_Drawing();
            $objDrawing->setName('Imagen');
            $objDrawing->setDescription('Etiqueta equipo'); 
            $ruta_img = "/imagen/code_barra.png"; 
            $objDrawing->setPath($ruta_img);
            $objDrawing->setCoordinates('AU'.$fila_i);
            $objDrawing->setHeight(30); 
            $objDrawing->setWorksheet($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet());

            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('AU' . $fila_i)->applyFromArray($EstiloBordeCompleto);
```

Comment: sinceramente no entiendo que es lo que tienes, que es lo que hace actualmente y cual es el error o parte que no fiunciona... puedes por favor dar una explicacion mas detallada?